# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in loop background worker

Tags: c#, listview, for-loop, backgroundworker

I'm trying to change a listview in the background worker.

```
 private void bw2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String temp = "aaaa";
        int n;
        int nNet;
        String[] ar = (String[])e.Argument;
        int nList = int.Parse(ar[3]);

        String tTrain = ar[0];
        String tPredic = ar[1];
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { nList = inputList.Items.Count; }));
        for (int i = 0; i < nList; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem temp1 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
            temp1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            temp1.Text = "NORMAL";
             this.BeginInvoke( new MethodInvoker( () => { temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", dtrainTextBox.Text , inputList.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text); }));
          //  temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", tTrain, inputList.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            if (!File.Exists(temp))
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList.Items[i].SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Red; }));
              //  inputList.Items[i].SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", dpredicTextBox.Text, inputList.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text); }));
           // temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", tPredic, inputList.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
            if (!File.Exists(temp))
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList.Items[i].SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Red; }));
               // inputList.Items[i].SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("i:{0} nList:{1}",i,nList));
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { temp = inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text; }));
            //temp = inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
            if (int.TryParse(temp, out n) & int.TryParse(ar[2], out nNet))
            {
                if (n > nNet)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red; }));
                 //   inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    temp1.Text = "ERRO";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red; }));
               // inputList.Items[i].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }

            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{inputList.Items[i].SubItems.Add(temp1);}));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `nList` in the case I'm testing `nList = 2060` and I'm getting the error in one of the `inputList.Items[i]`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll Additional information:
>   InvalidArgument=Value of '2060' is not valid for 'index'.

I don't know how this is happening, the last value of "i" should be 2059, how is it trying to access this index 2060.
nList has inputList.Items.Count value, I passed it as argument so that i wouldnt need to use invoke in order to get its count.

I just tried this:

```
 private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] ar = { dpredicTextBox.Text, dpredicTextBox.Text, nNet.Items.Count,  inputList};
        bw3.RunWorkerAsync(ar);
    }
private void bw3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String temp = "aaaa";
        int n;
        object[] ar = (Object[])e.Argument;
        ListView nList = (ListView) ar[3];
        int nNet = (int)ar[2];
        String tTrain = (String) ar[0];
        String tPredic = (String) ar[1];
        foreach(ListViewItem item in nList.Items)
        {
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem temp1 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
            temp1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            temp1.Text = "NORMAL";
            temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", tTrain, item.SubItems[1].Text); 
            if (!File.Exists(temp))
            {

                item.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }
            temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", tPredic, item.SubItems[2].Text);
            if (!File.Exists(temp))
            {
                item.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }
            temp = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            if (int.TryParse(temp, out n))
            {
                if (n > nNet)
                {
                    item.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    temp1.Text = "ERRO";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                item.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                temp1.Text = "ERRO";
            }
            item.SubItems.Add(temp1);
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList = nList; }));
        }
       // this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { inputList = nList; }));
    }
```

But its also not working:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'inputList' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Why you dont use `i < inputList.Count`? in your for-loop.

Comment: @hofmeister I think you mean `i < inputList.Items.Count`.

Comment: nList has inputList.Items.Count value

Comment: The list view may have a blank row for data entry the is adding one to the number of items.  Your may have the header row as one of the rows of data and one to the value.  Normally the headers are hidden at row -1.

Comment: @juharr ofc, thanks.

Comment: The exception would be a null pointer or something and not out of range if the problem was the lastrow being blank.

Comment: What's the point of that background worker if every other line is invoking something on the main thread?  Only put the time consuming part in the background worker.

Comment: Its a listview, this backgroundworker is supossed to check the entire listview and change the background color of the cell that contains something wrong.The invokers are all inside ifs and will only be called if there is something in the cell.

Comment: Based on what you posted, you don't need a background worker.

Comment: Why not?
The listview has more than 4k entries. If I try to check everything and change the cells to red when there is something wrong, then the form freezes for a few seconds until everything is done. I dont want it freezing.
I forgot to mention,when there is something wrong,the subitem thats wrong becomes red,and another subitem with red color is also added.
If there is nothing wrong,it adds a subitem with greencolor.

Comment: Let's turn this around: why are you showing the user 4k rows?  That's a lot of data for the user to deal with.  Create a list for the user that has just the "something wrong" items, since that is their work flow.  Anyways, it looks like you are actually making things slower with your code since you are BeginInvoking so much.  What you really need to do is separate the data from the gui, so that you can just focus on the data, then fire any updates on the ListView control.  If anything is *freezing*, it's because there are too many invalidation updates (refreshes) going to your control.

Comment: What you said makes sense, but I was asked to place everything in the listview so the the listView has to show all the 4k.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `BeginInvoke`, which is asynchronous, use `Invoke`. Counter `i` in fact becomes 2060 in the end of the loop, and this can happen before `inputList.Items[i]` get referenced in one of your asynchronous calls. Calling the `Invoke` method on a WinForms control waits until the call is completed and makes the loop behave as you expect. Your second code sample does not work because WinForms controls can not be "touched" from a background thread. They can only be accessed from the main (or GUI) thread.